# React + Redux: Scrolling a DOM element after state change

Tags: reactjs, redux

New to Redux here, really just looking for a "best practice" answer.

I am building a chat application using React + Redux. My app looks something like this:

- 3 stateless components for my app container, message list, and input bar
- Actions for adding user messages/responses
- A reducer that takes in these actions and returns a messages array
- Chat middleware which handles a emitting a socket message when then ADD_MESSAGE action is dispatched

So far so good. Everything is working well, however I'm unsure of how/where in this sequence I should be making DOM manipulations. Specifically, I would like to scroll to the bottom of my `message-list` container whenever my messages state changes.

All I need to fire is something like: `messagesListElement.scrollTop = messagesListElement.scrollHeight;`, but not sure where the appropriate place to do this is.

Comment: Sounds like you're best bet is lifting your messagelist component into a class and listening for `componentDidUpdate` https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate I can write a more complete answer if that works for you.

Comment: Thanks this makes sense, that was an approach I was considering. Would be nice to keep my components stateless if possible, but this seems like the best solution

Comment: You can with recompose helpers https://github.com/acdlite/recompose

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mentioned that all the three components are stateless which means the messages are maintained in redux store which means they are passed as props to the child components. Basically there are five life cycle methods which could get triggered after/before the component gets updated.

- componentWillReceiveProps()
- shouldComponentUpdate()
- componentWillUpdate()
- componentDidUpdate()
- render()

Now since you want to scroll down after a new message is pushed to the messages state, the best place to do this would be **componentDidUpdate()**

**Why not componentWillReceiveProps** - This is the function which will get executed just before a new message is about to be passed in the new props of the component. This is the best place to update your component's state against the new props but since your component is stateless, this is not the right place for scrolling. [This](http://busypeoples.github.io/post/react-component-lifecycle/) could be helpful

Hope it helps :)

Comment: So since I'm using stateless components, in order to use these I'm assuming I should convert my components to use React.createClass? (As far as I'm aware, lifecycle methods are not available in stateless components). Thanks for your response!

Comment: Yes lifecycle methods are not available in stateless components, if you want to use them you have to use **React.createClass** in es5 or **class <className> extends React.Component**. Although there is a library which provides lifecycle methods to stateless components but I haven't used it ever.  [Check it out here](https://github.com/davidmarkclements/react-functional).